# Is there a way to make this possible?

Tags: facebook, api

Can you let me know when a person 'Likes' my facebook page, I would 
give them a 10% discount, but will that person only get the discount 
the ONE time? I did a test as a new customer and click 'like' and 
ordered. but when I went back it looks like I can re-order as much as I 
want for a 10% discount. 
this should be ONLY ONE time. 
Is there a way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can check *if* a person has liked your page, but you cant get a callback when they actually do it. Also there are strict rules on rewarding users for liking your page/app etc so make sure you read the guide fully before implementing something you could be told off for:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/

Comment: i was checked the page you are provide, & i think it is okay! that i am correct, well i think you don't understand my question.. i want to give only one time 10% discount for a new users... not again & again.. i need some help..

Answer (score 0):

Make the coupon codes usable only once in your backend?